# How to run an application on a disk partition ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem

I have loaded /dev/pmem0 filesystem on /mnt/ramdisk.

output of df command:

> Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
>
> /dev/pmem0        307200     4120    303080   2% /mnt/ramdisk

I want to run some benchmarks on this partition - /mnt/ramdisk. How to make sure that an application runs on this partition? I'm a complete newbie for this and I want some suggestions or some startup material for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a clue about which sort of application you had in mind might clarify, however - if you copy your application, lets call it "app", to the partition, and type (from a console, obviously) `/mnt/ramdisk/app` then it will run this particular copy.
If you have problems doing so, it likely means you have a security system banning you from doing this - there are several, so a bit more detail in the question will be needed! Also check that the permissions for it have 'x' set (if you do `ls -l`). If not, `chmod +x app` will fix that.
Ordinarily, your system looks at the $PATH variable to decide which copy to run; `which app` will tell you which one it planned to use, `echo $PATH` will sort of explain why it chose that one.
Bear in mind, for benchmarking, that `app` may choose to use a different directory for data - depends what it is, of course. Also, multitasking systems don't lend themselves easily to simple benchmarking - do multiple runs, at least.

Comment: I want to run 2 applications: 1) Filebench 2) memcached (server-client based application). So should I need to copy the files to this folder and just running this will suffice?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, where these applications run from is immaterial - filebench writes to files in a directory you specify in the config, and memcached - isn't a benchmark it's a web caching tool, surely - this is really not going to care where it's executable is located, nor AFAICS will it use a drive location, it's a memory thing. By all means try it - you can compare results & see!